# pdoResourses, настройка фильтрации в &where

Tags: modx, pdoresource

Не могу корректно настроить вывод &where.
По синтаксису вроде все верно.

Нужно сделать так чтобы этот фильтр отфильтровывал на конкретных страницах ресурсы, у которых в tv-поле project_sort указано название (pagetitle) данной страницы, на которой и будут выводится эти ресурсы. Но вот беда, не получается.

Параметр ввода у tv-поля: Множественный выбор. Поэтому у ресурса может быть выбрано несколько страниц на которых он может быть выведен (вот почему и не использован &tvFilters, и вопроса наверное не было этого)

Вывод pdoResourses в шаблоне:

```html
<ul>
                             [[pdoMenu?
                                    &parents     = `3`
                                    &depth       = `0`
                                    &sortby      = `RAND()`
                                    &includeTVs  = `project_sort,tester,related_services`
                                    &resources   = `-12`
                                    &where       = `{"project_sort"=="%[[*pagetitle]]%"}`
                                    &showLog     = `1`
                                    &tpl         = `@INLINE <li><a href="[[+link]]">[[+pagetitle]]</a></li>`
                                ]]
                         </ul>
```

Приложу еще лог: (сам не понимаю здесь ничего)

```html
0.0005732: pdoTools loaded
0.0000150: xPDO query object created
0.0002820: Included list of tvs: project_sort, related_services
0.0001152: leftJoined modTemplateVarResource as TVproject_sort
0.0000942: leftJoined modTemplateVarResource as TVrelated_services
0.0001149: Added selection of modResource: `id`, `type`, `contentType`, `pagetitle`, `longtitle`, `description`, `alias`, `alias_visible`, `link_attributes`, `published`, `pub_date`, `unpub_date`, `parent`, `isfolder`, `introtext`, `content`, `richtext`, `template`, `menuindex`, `searchable`, `cacheable`, `createdby`, `createdon`, `editedby`, `editedon`, `deleted`, `deletedon`, `deletedby`, `publishedon`, `publishedby`, `menutitle`, `donthit`, `privateweb`, `privatemgr`, `content_dispo`, `hidemenu`, `class_key`, `context_key`, `content_type`, `uri`, `uri_override`, `hide_children_in_tree`, `show_in_tree`, `properties`
0.0000048: Added selection of modTemplateVarResource: IFNULL(`value`, '') AS `project_sort`
0.0000031: Added selection of modTemplateVarResource: IFNULL(`value`, '') AS `related_services`
0.0000429: Replaced TV conditions
0.0003350: Processed additional conditions
0.0006430: Added where condition: 0=, modResource.id:NOT IN(12), modResource.parent:IN(3,12,62,63,56,66,72,7,10,11,23,24,25,36,57,58,59,60,64,65,68,69,70,71,73,74), modResource.published=1, modResource.hidemenu=0, modResource.deleted=0, modResource.context_key=web
0.0000041: Replaced TV conditions
0.0000460: Sorted by RAND(), ASC
0.0001700: SQL prepared "SELECT `modResource`.`id`, `modResource`.`type`, `modResource`.`contentType`, `modResource`.`pagetitle`, `modResource`.`longtitle`, `modResource`.`description`, `modResource`.`alias`, `modResource`.`alias_visible`, `modResource`.`link_attributes`, `modResource`.`published`, `modResource`.`pub_date`, `modResource`.`unpub_date`, `modResource`.`parent`, `modResource`.`isfolder`, `modResource`.`introtext`, `modResource`.`content`, `modResource`.`richtext`, `modResource`.`template`, `modResource`.`menuindex`, `modResource`.`searchable`, `modResource`.`cacheable`, `modResource`.`createdby`, `modResource`.`createdon`, `modResource`.`editedby`, `modResource`.`editedon`, `modResource`.`deleted`, `modResource`.`deletedon`, `modResource`.`deletedby`, `modResource`.`publishedon`, `modResource`.`publishedby`, `modResource`.`menutitle`, `modResource`.`donthit`, `modResource`.`privateweb`, `modResource`.`privatemgr`, `modResource`.`content_dispo`, `modResource`.`hidemenu`, `modResource`.`class_key`, `modResource`.`context_key`, `modResource`.`content_type`, `modResource`.`uri`, `modResource`.`uri_override`, `modResource`.`hide_children_in_tree`, `modResource`.`show_in_tree`, `modResource`.`properties`, IFNULL(`TVproject_sort`.`value`, '') AS `project_sort`, IFNULL(`TVrelated_services`.`value`, '') AS `related_services` FROM `modx_site_content` AS `modResource` LEFT JOIN `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues` `TVproject_sort` ON `TVproject_sort`.`contentid` = `modResource`.`id` AND `TVproject_sort`.`tmplvarid` = 28 LEFT JOIN `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues` `TVrelated_services` ON `TVrelated_services`.`contentid` = `modResource`.`id` AND `TVrelated_services`.`tmplvarid` = 51 WHERE  ( `modResource`.`id` NOT IN (12) AND `modResource`.`parent` IN (3,12,62,63,56,66,72,7,10,11,23,24,25,36,57,58,59,60,64,65,68,69,70,71,73,74) AND `modResource`.`published` = 1 AND `modResource`.`hidemenu` = 0 AND `modResource`.`deleted` = 0 AND `modResource`.`context_key` = 'web' )  ORDER BY RAND() ASC "
0.0017741: SQL executed
0.0000651: Rows fetched
0.0001140: Returning raw data
0.0000129: Tree was built
0.0000060: Start template tree
0.0001550: Created inline "modChunk" with name "8c8db39859c1f8dfc1c82bdf6cfaaac9"
0.0028331: End template tree
0.0000761: Created inline "modChunk" with name "dc6d3757597108f87f958f868cf1591a"
0.0072160: Total time
10 485 760: Memory usage
```

Answer (score 1):

`&where` это массив дополнительных параметров выборки, закодированный в JSON. Синтаксис можно посмотреть тут: https://docs.modx.com/xpdo/2.x/class-reference/xpdoquery/xpdoquery.where

В вашем случае будет так:

```
&where       = `{"project_sort:LIKE":"'%[[*pagetitle]]%'"}`
```

Заметьте, не равно а LIKE т.е. проверяется именно вхождение одной строки `[[*pagetitle]]` в другой `project_sort`